# Is the !boolean a atomic operation in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can the code below can work in multithreading? Is the !boolean a atomic operation in java?

```
volatile boolean flag = true;
if (!flag){
    do something
}
```

Comment: Even if it is, once you enter the if body what stops it from changing values again? How is this different from it changing during the `not`? Why does your code depend on this being atomic?

Comment: It's an atomic read (regardless of `volatile`), but `do something` is not atomic with respect to the preceding check, unless you synchronize it.

Comment: Why not use AtomicBoolean object?

Comment: @cricket_007 There's no update in the question.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the "atomicity" you asked?  I suspect it is an X-Y question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `!boolean` a[n] atomic operation in java?

No. There are three operations here:

1. Load the variable
2. Compare and branch.
3. 'do something'.

A thread-switch can occur between 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, and the value of the underlying boolean can change at either time, or during 3, or after it.

So if you want to be sure that 'do something' only happens if `flag` is *simultaneously* false, you will have to synchronize, or use a semaphore.

Comment: This is misleading, at best. The read itself is atomic (as opposed to, say, a non-volatile long). There's no significance in the fact that the variable may change between loading and comparing. What's significant is that the variable can change *any time* after the read without additional synchronization.

Comment: @shmosel '*No* significance?' Really?

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? Do you have an example where there would be an observable difference in behavior purely because loading and comparing is not atomic?

Comment: I am on @shmosel 's view too.  OP is asking for `!boolean` being atomic, not whole `if (!flag){do something}`.  Under such context, there is no significance

Comment: @AdrianShum There is no difference, as neither is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's marked `volatile` and the value is a primitive, you are guaranteed that the read will always be consistent (no possibility of reading a partially-initialized value).

Even if it weren't marked `volatile`, the JVM will always atomically read any primitive value that is stored in 32 bits or smaller. This is a requirement of the language in [JLS 17.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6). (JLS 17.7, which allows "word tearing" for 64-bit primitive values, namely `long` and `double`, says that this behavior is implementation-specific. In practice, on all production 64-bit JVM implementations I know of, reads of even 64-bit values are always atomic.)

The operation of inverting the boolean may not be atomic with the read, but if so it will work by copying the boolean value to the JVM instruction stack, so there's still no possibility of data corruption (since pushing the value onto the operand stack is an atomic operation). More likely, the JIT will just invert your `if` condition and jump to the other branch rather than actually inverting the boolean value.

Of course, you still don't have any guarantee you won't read the value immediately before it is changed by another thread, so literally the very next instruction may begin executing concurrently with the boolean being set to true by another thread.

Comment: There is a race, and the JVM doesn't read longs or doubles atomically.

Comment: `volatile` does nothing to ensure atomicity in this case.

Comment: "atomicity" and "race" are different aren't they?

Comment: @AdrianShum: Indeed they are different. I was sloppy in my wording. I've cleaned that up now, thanks.

Comment: @EJP: Of course there's a race -- I was sloppy with my wording before. There's no way word tearing can occur here though. And in practice, long and double don't exhibit word tearing on a 64-bit JVM (although the spec allows it).

Comment: I am not aware that volatile can avoid partial update. Is it mentioned somewhere in JLS ?

Comment: @AdrianShum: `volatile` ensures a happens-before edge. Doesn't that by necessity ensure you can't get word tearing? (To be clear, I'm only talking about primitive values here.)

Comment: @DanielPryden It seems to me that's a reasonable assumption but I just wonder if it is necessarily valid.  Anyway, I got the answer from JLS :)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7  And what you said is explicitly mentioned and is true :)